# Are $\left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} | |y| > x^2 , |y| < 10 \right\} $ & $\left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}| |y| > x^4 , |y| < 10 \right\} $ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Are spaces $A=\left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}  |  |y| > x^2 , |y| < 10 \right\} $  and $B=\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} |  |y| > x^4 , |y| < 10 \right\} $ homeomorphic?
My answer is that they are because if we construct a function $ f \colon ClA \to ClB $ $ f(x, x^2) =(x,x^4) $ then f would be a continuous bijection and as $ClA$ is compact f would be a homeomorphism. Thus the restriction of f to A is also a homeomorphism.

Comment: Can you construct a homeomorphism between e.g. $\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\leq1\}$ and $\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\leq4\}$? Also here one is a subset of the other. I don't see why that should be an obstacle.

Comment: What is (x,y)(x,y)?

Comment: sorry I corrected it

Answer (score 2):

Let's disect those sets. Both of them consist of two connected components: when $y<0$ and when $y>0$. It is enough that we show that those components are pairwise homeomorphic. And since each upper half component is a reflection of the lower half then it is enough to show that $A=\{(x,y)\ |\ y>x^2; y< 10\}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\ |\ y>x^4; y< 10\}$ are homeomorphic.

To do that you have to realize that both $f(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=x^4$ are convex functions. A bit of work has to be done to make sure that these conditions together with $y<10$ imply that both $A$ and $B$ are open and **convex** subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. And it is well known that [every open and convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to a $n$-ball](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/geschke/papers/ConvexOpen.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can see this directly. Note that for $(x,y) \in A$ we have $x^2 < 10$, i.e. $\lvert x \rvert < \sqrt{10}$ and for $(x,y) \in B$ we have $\lvert x \rvert < \sqrt[4]{10}$. Define $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \phi(x) = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt[4]{10}}$. This is a linear homeomorphism which maps the open interval $(-\sqrt{10},\sqrt{10})$ onto $(-\sqrt[4]{10},\sqrt[4]{10})$.

Define
$$f : A \to B, f(x,y) = \left(\phi(x),\text{sgn}(y)\left(\phi(x)^4 + \dfrac{10 - \phi(x)^4}{10 - x^2}(\lvert y \rvert - x^2)\right)\right) .$$
Note that the $\text{sgn}$-function is continuous because $y = 0$ is impossible. Geometrically the line segments between $(x,x^2)$ and $(x,10)$ are mapped linearly onto the line segments between $(\phi(x),\phi(x)^4)$ and $(\phi(x),10)$ and the line segments between $(x,-x^2)$ and $(x,-10)$ are mapped linearly onto the line segments between $(\phi(x),-\phi(x)^4)$ and $(\phi(x),-10)$.

An inverse for $f$ is given by
$$g : B \to A, g(x,y) = \left(\phi^{-1}(x), \text{sgn}(y)\left(\phi^{-1}(x)^2 + \dfrac{10 - \phi^{-1}(x)^2}{10 - x^4}(\lvert y \rvert - x^4)\right) \right) .$$
If you want you can formally check that $g \circ f = id_A$ and $f \circ g = id_B$.